# How can I apply multiprocessing to this function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

I wrote a little script which scrapes a platform for job advertisments, everything working pretty fine but really slow, since im iterating through up to 200 advertisments for information. While I still think I could code some stuff better to make it run faster aswell, the fact that I couldnt get multiprocessing working here is what bothers me most.

These are the functions, which do the main work, i was trying to add an intern function for the for loop in def get_all_job_details() to map it, but it would always throw an PicklingError or sometimes i got "Expected exactly 2 arguments 3 given" in open_file() which i cant understand tbh.

```
def get_job_links(section_URL):
    soup = make_soup(section_URL)
    internerLink = soup.find_all("a", "internerLink primaerElement")
    job_links = [BASE_URL + link["href"] for link in internerLink]
    return job_links


def get_all_job_links(section_URL):
    all_job_links = []
    for page in range(1, PAGE_COUNT + 1):
        newURL = section_URL[:-1] + str(page)
        all_job_links.extend(get_job_links(newURL))
    return all_job_links


def get_job_details(job_URL):
    soup = make_soup(job_URL)
    details = {'job_URL': job_URL, 'refnr': '', 'firmName': '',
               'fName': '', 'sName': '', 'adressStr': '',
               'adressPlz': '', 'adressOrt': '', 'email': '',
               'jobtype': '', 'gender': '', 'status': ''}

    [details.update({'refnr': refnr.text}) for refnr in soup.findAll(id=re.compile("referenznummer"))]
    [details.update({'firmName': firmName.text}) for firmName in
     soup.findAll(id=re.compile("ruckfragenundbewerbungenan_-2147483648"))]
    [details.update({'fName': fName.text + ' '}) for fName in soup.findAll(id=re.compile("vorname_-2147483648"))]
    [details.update({'sName': sName.text}) for sName in soup.findAll(id=re.compile("nachname_-2147483648"))]
    [details.update({'adressStr': adressStr.text}) for adressStr in
     soup.findAll(id=re.compile("ruckfragenUndBewerbungenAn.wert\['adresse'\]Strasse_-2147483648"))]
    [details.update({'adressPlz': adressPlz.text}) for adressPlz in
     soup.findAll(id=re.compile("ruckfragenUndBewerbungenAn.wert\['adresse'\]Plz_-2147483648"))]
    [details.update({'adressOrt': adressOrt.text}) for adressOrt in
     soup.findAll(id=re.compile("ruckfragenUndBewerbungenAn.wert\['adresse'\]Ort_-2147483648"))]
    [details.update({'email': str(email['href'])[7:]}) for email in
     soup.findAll(id=re.compile("vermittlung.stellenangeboteverwalten.detailszumstellenangebot.email"))]

    jobtype = soup.b
    if jobtype:
        jobtype = soup.b.text
    else:
        jobtype = ''
    if jobtype.find("Anwendungsentwicklung") > -1:
        details.update({'jobtype': u"Fachinformatiker für Anwendungsentwicklung"})
    elif jobtype.find("Systemintegration") > -1:
        details.update({'jobtype': u"Fachinformatiker für Systemintegration"})
    elif jobtype.find("Medieninformatik") > -1:
        details.update({'jobtype': u"Medieninformatiker"})
    elif jobtype.find("Informatikkaufmann") > -1:
        details.update({'jobtype': u"Informatikkaufmann"})
    elif jobtype.find("Systemkaufmann") > -1:
        details.update({'jobtype': u"IT-Systemkaufmann"})
    else:
        details.update({'jobtype': u"Informatiker"})

    soup.find("div", {"class": "ausklappBox"}).decompose()
    genderdiv = str(soup.div)
    gender = ''
    if genderdiv.find("Frau") > -1:
        gender += "Frau "
    if genderdiv.find("Herr") > -1:
        gender += "Herr "
    if len(gender) > 5:
        gender = ''
    details.update({'gender': gender})
    return details


def get_all_job_details(section_URL):
    all_job_details = []
    all_job_links = get_all_job_links(section_URL)
    for i in range(len(all_job_links)):
        all_job_details.append(get_job_details(all_job_links[i]))
        printProgress(i, len(all_job_links) - 1, prefix='Progress:', suffix='Complete', barLength=50)
    return all_job_details

def printProgress(iteration, total, prefix='', suffix='', decimals=2, barLength=100):
"""
Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
@params] =
    iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
    total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
    prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
    suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
    decimals    - Optional  : number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
    barLength   - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
"""
filledLength = int(round(barLength * iteration / float(total)))
percents = round(100.00 * (iteration / float(total)), decimals)
bar = '#' * filledLength + '-' * (barLength - filledLength)
Sys.stdout.write('%s [%s] %s%s %s\r' % (prefix, bar, percents, '%', suffix)),
Sys.stdout.flush()
if iteration == total:
    print("\n\n")
```

So how do I do it correctly?

Comment: Is the problem in the printProgress function? Can you show us that code?

Comment: i dont think so, i tried it with and without the printprogress function EDIT: added function

Comment: I doubt this is related to your issue, but it seems like *really* bad style to me to use list comprehensions for their side-effects. Why not just reorder things and write regular `for` loops?

Comment: @Blckknght Do you care to elaborate? I used it because it was presented to me as a pretty good solution for what i was doing, not sure why but im a python noob so what do i know. What are side-effects of using list-comprehensions for example?

Comment: A list comprehension builds a list from the expressions you put in it. You're using `details.update()` as your expression, which always returns `None`, so it builds a list of `None` values. You then throw away the list (since you're not assigning it to anything), which makes building it pretty silly. The side effect is that the `details` dictionary gets modified. You can get the same result with `for refnr in soup.findAll(id=re.compile("referenznummer")): details['refnr'] = refnr.text` (you could still use an `update` call, but there's no need when you can do an assignment statement).

Comment: @Blckknght oh wait, I actually remember know why i used list comprehension, at first I was using a list later i decided to go with a list of dictionaries because it seemed easier to access the values by keys. I think I was just too scared to change the structure of anything working in my code since I had enough dealing with unicode errors -.-